# Extracting data from a tab-delimited file with JavaScript

Tags: asp-classic, coldfusion, csv, jscript

I'm trying to extract data from a data file that's tab-delimited (in some parts), and really seems like it's going to be a headache to work out (I reallw wish they could just have CSV-ed it).

Here's the data:

http://www.fededirectory.frb.org/FedACHdir.txt

Here's the format description:

www.fededirectory.frb.org/format_ACH.cfm

I'd like to extract this data and store it in a database with serverside javascript, (ASP). Any ideas?

Comment: is not tab delimited... is delimited by position

Comment: If you look at the data, only some of it is in the same location consistently - the address, for example, is a variable length and I don't see any way to separate it from the address that comes afterwards.

Comment: Of course it does... the address is delimited from position 72  to position 107...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not `tab delimited`... it is `position delimited`.

To handle the file using `javascript`, the file must be on the same server and available via `HTTP`.

If you need to upload the file to some server, the server side language need to extract all the data based on your [layout file](http://www.fededirectory.frb.org/format_ACH.cfm)

In order to extract it... you must for example do something like:

```
String line = "011000015O0110000150020802000000000FEDERAL RESERVE BANK                1000 PEACHTREE ST N.E.              ATLANTA             GA303094470866234568111     ";
String routingNumber = line.substring(0,8);
String officeCode = line.substring(8,9);
String servicingNumber = line.substring(9,17);
String typeCode = line.substring(17,18);
...
...
...
String filler = line.substring(151,line.length());
```

And `iterate` that code for every line in your file.

In pseudo-code :

```
for (Line line in File)  {
  // do the code above
}
```

***Note:*** Process that file with `JavaScript` will be painful I recommend to do it in the server side of your application.